# phonegap Geolocation in android 4.2&4.0 versions not working but good in 2.3,4.1

Tags: geolocation, cordova

I have developed simple geolocation application using phonegap 2.7.0 it's perfectly working on android 2.3 and 4.1 devices but not in 4.2 &4.0

1.enable location checked.
2.enable javascript checked.
3.wifi and gps enabld.

thanks in advance
arivu.